# Import DateTime using Nemo/Alice bundle

Tags: symfony, datetime, yaml, fixtures

My question is about this bundle: https://github.com/nelmio/alice in combination with Symfony2.

I have some fixture i want to load in my new website, and this bundle is great for that. I created some YML files and consider the following YML as my fixturedata:

```
DateTime (local):
    news-date-1:
        __construct: ['2014-07-01']

Stef\BVBundle\Entity\Blog:
    StefBVBundle-Blog-1:
        title: 'A day with blah'
        blog: 'e5645646'
        image: 'beach.jpg'
        author: 'dsyph3r'
        tags: 'symfony2, php, paradise, symblog'
        created: @news-date-1
        updated: @news-date-1
    StefBVBundle-Blog-2:
        id: 1
        title: 'meeeh'
        author: dsyph3r
        blog: '5rw5425'
        image: beach.jpg
        tags: 'symfony2, php, paradise, symblog'
        created: '2014-07-01T00:00:00+0200'
        updated: '2014-07-01T00:00:00+0200'
```

The one labelled with 'StefBVBundle-Blog-1' works like a charm, it knows 'created' and 'updated' are \DateTime values.

But 'StefBVBundle-Blog-2' causes an error, because the Nemo/Alice bundle consider it as a string, instead of a DateTime. Is it possible to do the DateTime-part inline?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

PHP Expressions inside <( )> are simply passed to Doctrine, so this will do the work :

```yml
Stef\BVBundle\Entity\Blog:
    StefBVBundle-Blog-2:
        created: <(new \DateTime('2014-02-02'))>
```

Comment: Documentation : https://github.com/nelmio/alice/blob/master/doc/customizing-data-generation.md#default-providers

Comment: created: <dateTime('2014-02-02')>

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the doc of [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderdatetime) library, you have to specify a DateTime instance, or DateTimeBetween with no time-laps if you want an exact date.

Your code, with correction:

```
DateTime (local):
    news-date-1:
        __construct: ['2014-07-01']

Stef\BVBundle\Entity\Blog:
    StefBVBundle-Blog-1:
        title: 'A day with blah'
        blog: 'e5645646'
        image: 'beach.jpg'
        author: 'dsyph3r'
        tags: 'symfony2, php, paradise, symblog'
        created: @news-date-1
        updated: @news-date-1
    StefBVBundle-Blog-2:
        id: 1
        title: 'meeeh'
        author: dsyph3r
        blog: '5rw5425'
        image: beach.jpg
        tags: 'symfony2, php, paradise, symblog'
        created: <dateTimeBetween('0 days', '2014-07-01T00:00:00+0200')>
        updated: <dateTimeBetween('0 days', '2014-07-01T00:00:00+0200')>
```

Didn't try, but should work.

Comment: Well, I did try it just now, but it feels a bit hacky. the syntax is . I made it now into:

        id: 1
        title: 'meeeh'
        author: dsyph3r
        blog: '5rw5425'
        image: beach.jpg
        tags: 'symfony2, php, paradise, symblog'
        created: <dateTimeBetween('2014-07-01T00:00:00+0200', '2014-07-01T00:00:00+0200')>
        updated: <dateTimeBetween('2014-07-01T00:00:00+0200', '2014-07-01T00:00:00+0200')>

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Thank you Soullivaneuh, it's better to use bundle function than DateTime, just RTFM, best ask here !!

Comment: Actually, the Paul's example is also officially documented and better fit the need. Didn't know about this new feature, looks great!